# Apache Sling Deployment Issues in Wildfly 24.0.1-Final

Tags: sling, wildfly-22

We have developed custom Apache Sling application and deployed in Wildfly 13.0.0-Final and running successfully. We are planning to upgrade the Application Server to Wildfly 24.0.1Final version. While deploying custom Apache Sling application in Wildfly 24.0.1-Final receiving following deployment errors.

```
2021-09-08 15:23:13 ERROR servlet:392 - ERROR: Error starting slinginstall:d:\mnt\SlingFileSystem\data\sling\startup\1\org.apache.felix.http.bridge-3.0.18.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4148)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

We are tried Servlet version 3.1.0, 3.5.0 and 4.0.0, but still facing same issues while deploying the application.

Here is the complete error list

```
15:22:47,848 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) Initializing Mojarra 2.3.14.SP04 for context ''
2021-09-08 15:23:13 ERROR servlet:392 - ERROR: Error starting slinginstall:d:\mnt\SlingFileSystem\data\sling\startup\1\org.apache.felix.http.bridge-3.0.18.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4148)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-09-08 15:23:14 ERROR servlet:392 - ERROR: Error starting launchpad:/resources/install/5/org.apache.felix.webconsole-4.3.4.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.http)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.http)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.http)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.http)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4148)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-09-08 15:23:14 ERROR servlet:392 - ERROR: Error starting launchpad:/resources/install/5/org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.ds-2.0.6.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.ds [29](R 29.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.ds [29](R 29.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole.i18n)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.http)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.ds [29](R 29.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole.i18n)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.ds [29](R 29.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.ds [29](R 29.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole.i18n)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.http)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.ds [29](R 29.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole.i18n)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4148)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-09-08 15:23:14 ERROR servlet:392 - ERROR: Error starting launchpad:/resources/install/5/org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.obr-1.0.4.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.obr [32](R 32.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.obr [32](R 32.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.http)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.obr [32](R 32.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.obr [32](R 32.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.obr [32](R 32.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.http)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.obr [32](R 32.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4148)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-09-08 15:23:14 ERROR servlet:392 - ERROR: Error starting launchpad:/resources/install/5/org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.packageadmin-1.0.4.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.packageadmin [33](R 33.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.packageadmin [33](R 33.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.http)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.packageadmin [33](R 33.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.packageadmin [33](R 33.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.packageadmin [33](R 33.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.http)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.packageadmin [33](R 33.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4148)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-09-08 15:23:14 ERROR servlet:392 - ERROR: Error starting launchpad:/resources/install/5/org.apache.sling.commons.log.webconsole-1.0.0.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.commons.log.webconsole [35](R 35.0): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.commons.log.webconsole [35](R 35.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.http)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.commons.log.webconsole [35](R 35.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.commons.log.webconsole [35](R 35.0): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.commons.log.webconsole [35](R 35.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.http)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.commons.log.webconsole [35](R 35.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4148)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-09-08 15:23:14 ERROR servlet:392 - ERROR: Error starting launchpad:/resources/install/5/org.apache.sling.extensions.webconsolesecurityprovider-1.0.0.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.extensions.webconsolesecurityprovider [38](R 38.0): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.extensions.webconsolesecurityprovider [38](R 38.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole)(version>=3.1.0)) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.http)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.extensions.webconsolesecurityprovider [38](R 38.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole)(version>=3.1.0))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.extensions.webconsolesecurityprovider [38](R 38.0): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.extensions.webconsolesecurityprovider [38](R 38.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole)(version>=3.1.0)) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.http)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.extensions.webconsolesecurityprovider [38](R 38.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole)(version>=3.1.0))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4148)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-09-08 15:23:14 ERROR servlet:392 - ERROR: Error starting launchpad:/resources/install/10/org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter-1.2.2.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter [41](R 41.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter [41](R 41.0)] osgi.implementation; (&(osgi.implementation=osgi.http)(version=1.0)) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter [41](R 41.0)] osgi.implementation; (&(osgi.implementation=osgi.http)(version=1.0))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter [41](R 41.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter [41](R 41.0)] osgi.implementation; (&(osgi.implementation=osgi.http)(version=1.0)) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter [41](R 41.0)] osgi.implementation; (&(osgi.implementation=osgi.http)(version=1.0))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4148)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-09-08 15:23:19 ERROR servlet:392 - ERROR: Error starting launchpad:/resources/install/15/org.apache.sling.jcr.davex-1.3.8.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.jcr.davex [69](R 69.0): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.jcr.davex [69](R 69.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.sling.api.resource)(version>=2.1.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.api [121](R 121.0): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.api [121](R 121.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.jcr.davex [69](R 69.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.sling.api.resource)(version>=2.1.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.jcr.davex [69](R 69.0): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.jcr.davex [69](R 69.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.sling.api.resource)(version>=2.1.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.api [121](R 121.0): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.api [121](R 121.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.jcr.davex [69](R 69.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.sling.api.resource)(version>=2.1.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4148)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-09-08 15:23:19 ERROR servlet:392 - ERROR: Error starting launchpad:/resources/install/15/org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.accessmanager-3.0.0.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.accessmanager [70](R 70.0): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.accessmanager [70](R 70.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.accessmanager [70](R 70.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.accessmanager [70](R 70.0): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.accessmanager [70](R 70.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.accessmanager [70](R 70.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4148)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-09-08 15:23:19 ERROR servlet:392 - ERROR: Error starting launchpad:/resources/install/15/org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.usermanager-2.2.6.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.usermanager [71](R 71.0): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.usermanager [71](R 71.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.usermanager [71](R 71.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.usermanager [71](R 71.0): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.usermanager [71](R 71.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.usermanager [71](R 71.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4148)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-09-08 15:23:19 ERROR servlet:392 - ERROR: Error starting launchpad:/resources/install/15/org.apache.sling.jcr.webconsole-1.0.2.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.jcr.webconsole [74](R 74.0): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.jcr.webconsole [74](R 74.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.http)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.jcr.webconsole [74](R 74.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.jcr.webconsole [74](R 74.0): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.jcr.webconsole [74](R 74.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.webconsole [28](R 28.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.http)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.jcr.webconsole [74](R 74.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.webconsole)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4148)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-09-08 15:23:19 ERROR servlet:392 - ERROR: Error starting launchpad:/resources/install/15/org.apache.sling.jcr.webdav-2.3.8.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.jcr.webdav [75](R 75.0): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.jcr.webdav [75](R 75.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.http)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.jcr.webdav [75](R 75.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.http)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.sling.jcr.webdav [75](R 75.0): missing requirement [org.apache.sling.jcr.webdav [75](R 75.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.http)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.http.bridge [7](R 7.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.sling.jcr.webdav [75](R 75.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.http)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4148)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2118)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1372)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: what is the version of `javax.servlet` provided by wildfly, it has to be `>=3.1.0` && below `4.0.0`